# AMD E1-6010 1.35GHz slow performance?

Tags: system-installation, performance, cpu, amd-processor

I have just installed the 64bit version of ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS version on my low-end laptop which has a AMD Dual-Core E1-6010 Accelerated Processor (1.35GHz, 1MB L2 Cache) and 4g of ram. Been switched from windows 7, I found my fresh installed ubuntu system is experiencing some serious lagging and delaying from the moment every time it booted up. Is it because of my processor or am I missing something?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The FSB and RAM speeds will also be slower than newer computers, which will doubtless be adding to the delays.

I would say you might be better with a low-overhead distribution such as LUbuntu or LXLE.

I have a couple of older laptops that by rights should be fine, but don't seem to cope with the latest distro either. Such is life, unfortunately.

You can try the 32-bit version of Ubuntu, and try to remove some of the bloat from the system, but as Ubuntu tends to be an 'everyman' kind of OS, you may not have much luck. Especially with Unity - it's quite resource-hungry in my (albeit limited) experience.

HTH,
edooze.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Eddie. I found that the problem was the 3d acceleration wasn't enabled, now everything runs fine :)

Comment: Wikipedia states that the E1-6010 is a 64-bit CPU from Q2 2014 and that the [front-side bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front-side_bus#Evolution) design was replaced with point-to-point connections by 2008.